# Getting page dimensions

Tags: nativescript

On navigating to a new page, how do I get the dimensions of the page - the client/layout area only - exclude the action bar if present.

Will I get the same notification when the device orientation changes?

Thanks.

Comment: To be able to handle the device orientation change, you could attach `orientationChanged` event listener to the application, which will notify you when the orientation has been changed. For example `application.on("orientationChanged", function(e:application.OrientationChangedEventData){
            console.log(e.newValue);
    });`

Answer (score 3):

Every view in NativeScript has a method call [getMeasuredHeight()](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view.html#getmeasuredheight) as well as [getMeasuredWidth()](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view.html#getmeasuredwidth). You can get the page dimensions like this:

```
var pageHeight, pageWidth;
pageHeight = page.getMeasuredHeight()- page.actionBar.getMeasuredHeight();
pageWidth = page.getMeasuredWidth()- page.actionBar.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: Yes I get this on the navigatedTo() event (not loading())...but...I get 0 dimension it if I go directly to this page from app.ts - if I switch away from the target page and then back again - the dimensions are set.

Comment: @dashman, wrap your code in "navigatedTo()"/"loaded" method into setTimeout and it will work properly. It seems NativeScript engine needs some more time to properly initialize the page.